# Battery or alternator issues

Tags: battery-drain

[image]

Hey so I just purchased a car put a new battery and alternator on it my kids left the door open for many hours and once I put the cables on the battery it'll crank but once the cables come off, the car cuts off as well sometimes it won't do it immediately after I'll have it running and after about 5 minutes it cuts off too. Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: The battery is just used to start the car. The alternator provides power to all the electrical bits, and charges the battery, when the car is running. If the car dies shortly after starting, then I suspect a bad alternator, or, as @RobertSBarnes said, a loose connection. (I wouldn't expect it to run, then die after minutes, if that were the case, but intermittent electrical connections are funny beasts.) Also, punctuation is your friend! :)

Answer (score 1):

since the battery and alternator are both new it sounds like you might have a loose battery cable or that it's not making a good connection.  it's also possible that by a fluke you got either a defective battery or alternator.  best to take it to an automotive electrician.